# Технологии для реализации трехуровневой архитектуры

Tags: c#, .net

Собственно вопрос скрывается в теме. Все что находится по трехуровневой архитектуре - статья в [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0). Каких-то конкретных примеров найти не могу. Как должны общаться между собой клиент и сервер приложений? В каком виде должны передаваться данные, полученные от БД клиенту. Все очень туманно в данном вопросе. Гугл предлагает так или иначе WinForm клиент + WCF/ASP.NET WebService/Remoting/... + SQL Server. Помогите. Направьте на путь истинный :)

Comment: В этом вопросе и ответах к нему есть немножко полезной информации: [Помогите с пониманием клиент-сервер (если клиенты разные) ?][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/257702/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: Крутой ответ. Держите нас в курсе ваших успехов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Трёхуровневая архитектура не более чем принцип. И строить её можно на любых технология, благо их миллион и маленькая тележка.

> Как должны общаться между собой клиент
> и сервер приложений?

гугли по словам "веб сервис", "soap", REST, "json rpc" и тд и тп.

> В каком виде должны передаваться
> данные, полученные от БД клиенту.

В любом, как удобнее для протокола обмена сообщениями между клиентом и сервером. Например JSON, XML, бинарно сериализованный объект и т.п.